# Does `/tmp` or `/private/tmp` on MacOS need to be world writable?

Tags: macos

I know that it is world writable by default but I'm wondering does it need to be? Does MacOS, the operating system, and any of its supporting apps, need `/tmp` `->` `/private/tmp` need to be world writable?

I can't find anything in Apple's documentations stating one way or another and was hoping someone else might know?

There are arguments to remove its world writable permission for better security because apps should be sandboxing their `tmp` in their own app directory.

Comment: `apps should be sandboxing their tmp in their own app directory.` ... this makes no sense to me.  Also.. "sandboxing??" .. ?? Apps should not be allowed to write in their own app directory.  /tmp/<app> is more like it.  Lock this down at your own peril.  Every engineer is told that they can write files here willy/nilly.. you will have nothing but problems if you play with the security of this folder.

Comment: Isn't that what sandboxing means? Each app has limited access to a limited folder that they can use. If they need temp storage then they would put it in the directory they can access. From a security perspective, you wouldn't want different apps to be see each other's content, even temp content.

Comment: Each app needs to call `NSTemporaryDirectory()` to get its path to the temporary directory (whatever the OS chooses for it).  This is true of both sandboxed and traditional apps.  Hopefully you and I can let the OS worry about the security.  Only an idiot would keep sensitive data in a temp file in the temp directory.. but alas.. I guess that DOES exist.  You will find that many apps use a hardcoded tmp path and locking it down will break them.  If that is your goal.. then blast away.  I meant no offense.  I am a mac programmer in addition to many other OSs.

Comment: I hear everything you’re saying. And I’m not necessarily arguing. I’m wondering what Apple’s official stance is on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lock down permissions on `/private/tmp` (which `/tmp` is a symlink to), then any software that tries to use it in a way that violates the permissions change will break (even if it used that directory in a safe way, which is entirely possible).

Let me run through how changing perms to `/private/tmp` would affect different types of software:

- Sandboxed apps (i.e. those that opt in to macOS's sandbox mechanism) are mostly restricted to their own sandbox container (under `~/Library/Containers`), with limited access to anything outside that. I don't think they're allowed to use `/private/tmp` at all (no matter what the perms on it are). Unless there's an [entitlement](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW5) that'd allow them access to it -- but I don't know of any that'd do that.
- Software that uses any of the standard ways to create/locate temporary files (including shell scripts that use `$TMPDIR` or `mktemp -t ...`) will automatically use a private (per-user) directory under `/var/folders/something...`, which is much more locked-down than you could do with `/private/tmp`.
- Software that uses `/private/tmp` *properly* (which isn't trivial, but as I said it's entirely possible) will probably just fail if your perms change doesn't allow access to it (maybe in a safe way, maybe not -- depends on the details).
- Software that uses `/private/tmp` *inproperly* will also probably just fail if your perms change doesn't allow access to it (again, maybe in a safe way, maybe not -- depends on the details).

So as far as I can see, locking down `/private/tmp` is most likely to just break some software, and probably create more problems than it solves.